# how to decompose in distribution so it will fit another distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling

I have to very different distributions of age based on two populations.
The first one includes about 750,000 cases with the following distribution(first picture) and another one of about 20,000 that has a completely different distribution (second picture ). How can I decompose the data set of the first picture to be as close as possible to the second picture distribution? : [image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What for? What is your research question in here?

Comment: Hello @Tim, my question is not about the research goal but about how to achieve near similar distributions. Later on, I'll use the same datasets to do some descriptive statistics. The easy thing to do is to take out all obs. >60. I wonder if there is a way to do something more sophisticated here.

Comment: What is your purpose? You can simply repeat each observation of given age the number of times that is proportional to the second distribution. There is a number of things you can do and they surely will lead to transforming your data to rubbish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first histogram to look like the second, it means you don't want to use age above, say, 60. Computationally, you can do a lot of things to make one pdf look like another, but if you think of it, you can't change the age of a subject, so there's no way you can say someone who is 80 is now 55 years old!

I believe what you have to do is maybe randomly sample subjects with age<80 from group 1 and build up a population and stop when the histogram frequencies are similar to group 2. In physics there is a method called "method of rejection sampling" for building up a pdf (histogram) of any shape. You would use the pdf values from group 2 to do the random sampling and rejection.

Comment: Seems what I was looking for, Are you aware for a code example in r for this issue?

Comment: it probably exists in R, search on rejection sampling in R.  See chap 7, Random Numbers, in Numerical Recipes by Press, Tuelkosky, Vetterling, Flannery, Cambridge Press, 2007.